# How to align-right or align-left with "\t"?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a list of names, dates of births, and ages. I want to print out each name, DOB, and Age accordingly, in a neat display. Example:

```
names = ["name112312", "name2123", "name3as"]
dob = ["jan112", "dec9", "augasd5"]
age = [1, 2, 123]
```

What I'm trying to print out is:

```
Name         DOB         Age

name112312   jan112       1

name2123     dec9         26

name3as      augasd5      123
```

Notice how it's aligned the same for each name, even if the name's aren't the same length.

This is what I'm trying to do, and this is what is currently happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMbVI.png

Code:

```
var list_DbU: Int

var db_nameS : Array = ["Bill", "Joe", "Sam", "Cathy"]
var db_dobS : Array = ["08:02:00", "01:25:96", "12:24:01", "04:03:99"]
var db_ageS : Array = [15, 19, 14, 16]


println("Db info: ")
println("Name \t DOB \t Age")
for list_DbU = 0; list_DbU < db_nameS.count; ++list_DbU {
    println("\n\(db_nameS[list_DbU]) \t \(db_dobS[list_DbU])")
}
```

Comment: Edit: So I guess I didn't properly format the text, so it's not aligned on the post, but hopefully you get the idea. Each name, dob, and age should be aligned with the "name", "dob", and "age" tabs at the top

Comment: Do the fields have a limit? Name max 20 characters? something on those lines?

Comment: As of now, no. I've thought of limiting it to say 15, and then doing a little math and adding spaces to each one based on the difference between the length of the name and the maximum characters allowed in the name, but I feel this would be a bit inefficient.

Comment: Your approach will work i.e. finding the difference and adding the required spaces. That is the only way you can left align the text and still keep it within the limits...

Comment: Thanks! I assumed it was, but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

use `NSString(format:)` can padding of width, `%-20s`, `20` is pading width of your field

```
var list_DbU: Int

var db_nameS : Array = ["Bill", "Joe", "Sam", "Cathy"]

    var db_dobS : Array = ["08:02:00", "01:25:96", "12:24:01", "04:03:99"]
    var db_ageS : Array = [15, 19, 14, 16]

    print("Db info: ")
    print(NSString(format: "%-20s%-20s%-20s", ("Name" as NSString).UTF8String, ("DOB" as NSString).UTF8String , ("Age" as NSString).UTF8String))
    for list_DbU = 0; list_DbU < db_nameS.count; ++list_DbU {
        let name = (db_nameS[list_DbU] as NSString).UTF8String
        var dob = (db_dobS[list_DbU] as NSString).UTF8String
        var age = db_ageS[list_DbU]
        print(NSString(format: "%-20s%-20s%d", name, dob, age))
    }
```

output:

```
Db info: 
Name                DOB                 Age                 
Bill                08:02:00            15
Joe                 01:25:96            19
Sam                 12:24:01            14
Cathy               04:03:99            16
```